# Come up with an equation that zig zags through numbers

Tags: algorithm

I have developed a program such that `i = 1` to `100`, 
the sequence of number should follow as

```
 1, 100, 2, 99, 3, 98, ...
```

based on the ith index. Just out of curiosity, is there a genius out there that can possibly come up with a *closed formula* given an *ith index*:

```
 f(i) = ?
```

you can find the appropriate number following the sequence mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

Given the function `f(i)` as a table

```
  i | f(i)
  ---------
  1 |   1
  2 | 100
  3 |   2
  4 |  99
  5 |   3
  6 |  98
  .....
```

You can put `f(i)` as a *closed formula*:

```
 f(i) = (i + 1) / 2 * (i % 2) + (101 - i / 2) * ((i + 1) % 2)
```

where `%` stands for *remainder*

Answer (score 1):

```
int f(int i) {
    return i % 2 == 0 ? (i / 2) : 101 - (i / 2);
}
```

Resulting;

```
1
100
2
99
3
98
4
...
```

Comment: @PaulR it was desperate, I was working during that time, but actually that floating point operation was unnecessary, as can be seen in my updated answer, alas still not as quaint as Dmitry's answer

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.